# Why is there no SessionFactoryUtils#applyTransactionTimeout anymore for hibernate 4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hi there I am migration an legacy application to spring 4.x and hibernate 4.2.x.

Everything went fine till now.

With hibernate 3 and spring 3 you could use `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils#applyTransactionTimeout(queryObject, sessionFactory)`

The `SessionFactoryUtils` for hibernate 4 does not have that method. Why? Is it not needed anymore? Do I have to set it differently?